# If $W_1 \subset W_2$, then is $W_1^ \perp \subset W_2^ \perp$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W_1$, $W_2$ subspaces for $V$.

If $W_1 \subset W_2$, then is  $W_1^ \perp \subset W_2^ \perp$ ?

I figured that if $W_1 \subset W_2 \implies W_1^ \perp \subset W_2$, but $W_2 \cap W_2^ \perp = \{0\}$, and hence $W_1^ \perp \not\subset W_2^ \perp$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If a line is contained in a plane, does that mean the plane normal to that line is contained in the line normal to that plane? Your inclusion should be reversed: $W_2^\perp \subset W_1^\perp$.

Comment: $W_1^{\perp} \subset W_2$ is also wrong. What happens when $W_1=W_2$?

Comment: What do you mean by $W_1^\perp$?

Comment: @twosigma, so just to make sure I understand, your line here is $W_1$, your plane is $W_2$, and $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes, that is one example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy then, to use some analogy from twosigma, let's say we have a line $W_1 = W_2$, and hence  $W_1^{\perp} \subset W_2$ would be implying that the normal plane to $W_1$ is contained in the line $W_2$, which is silly. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

$W^{\perp} = \left\lbrace v \in V : \langle v,w \rangle = 0 \hspace{0.2cm}\forall \hspace{0.2cm}  w \in W \right\rbrace$

If we consider $W_{1} \subset W_{2}$ and we take $w \in W_{2}^{\perp}$ we have by definition that $\langle v,w \rangle = 0 \hspace{0.2cm}\forall  v \in W_{2}$.

Since $W_{1} \subset W_{2}$ we have that $w$ is such that $\langle v,w \rangle = 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \forall \hspace{0.2cm} v \in W_{1}$, hence $W_{2}^{\perp} \subset W_{1}^{\perp}$